# Making my Facebook page un-interactive to fans until they Like the Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I want to do a contest on Facebook, and the qualifier will need the contestant to Like the page before he can participate. As it stands, I am unable to do that, because even those who haven't liked a fan page can comment on activities going on in the page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is called Like-gating and is explicitly not allowed in any way, no workarounds.

See Platform Policy for more info https://developers.facebook.com/policy